# Reading byte by byte HEIF/HEIC images XMP metadata

Tags: image-processing, bytecode, xmp, heic, heif

I am trying to build a native byte parser that given an HEIF image it returns back its metadata (mainly width and height of the image).
I am struggling a lot at the moment finding the right documentation and specs to use for parsing such info. I have to do such thing for both XMP and EXIF metadata, but let's focus only on XMP for now.

What I need is the exact byte structure of where to find what. According to the HEIF international standard doc ([here](https://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c066067_ISO_IEC_23008-12_2017.zip)):

> For image items, XMP metadata shall be stored as an item of item_type value 'mime' and content type'application/rdf+xml'. The body of the item shall be a valid XMP document, in XML form.

Perfect, if I analyse a sample image I can find such marker:

[image]

From now on I can't find anywhere how to get the info I need. I would expect something saying "the first 2 bytes are the header, with marker 0xFF 0xCE (just an example), the next 2 bytes are the width, and following 2 bytes the height...etc".
In my case I am going by intuition. My sample image is of dimensions 8736x5856. If in the tool I look for Big-Endian 2 byte integer 8736, I can find it:

[image]

And hey, 2 bytes later there is the 5856 height as well:

[image]

But again, I arrived here by luck and intuition. I need a proper schema that tells me where to find what in such a way that I can traslate it to code.

Comment: Hi, did you figure it out? added some more heif boxes support to fq master btw

Comment: Hi @MattiasWadman it is "kind of" going well yes, but I didn't answer below your post yet cause I am still digging through all the metadata and I may have some doubts about the MIME part. You definitely pointed me to the right path! Give me a bit more time to build the reader and I will definitely get back at you! Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! btw i was wrong about "mime" being a box, the "mime" string you see is the item_name of a "infe" box. In the HEIF file i looked at the infe mime box seems to be an empty rdf+xml string, not sure what that means.

Comment: @MattiasWadman you pointed me out to the right direction saying that HEIF is ISOBMFF based! so for that already you gave me the right answer and I thank you :) it's still being a bit tricky cause HEIF can be single or multiple images file. I made a photo with my phone, saved it as HEIF and it's still being written as multiple images file. In this case I also have different "ispe" boxes, even tho the image is only one. Do you know by any chance how to pinpoint the right ispe box to get the width and height?

Comment: Great to hear. Sorry don't know much about HEIF but i'm happy to have a look, could you share an example file somehow? maybe it's HDR etc? do all the ispe boxes have the same resolution? btw latest fq master has support for hevc sps/pps/vps which heif uses, might be interesting.

Comment: @MattiasWadman still haven't figured it out unfortunately.. sharing an image with you through WeTransfer link. I know this is an heic format, but it's simply 1 single heif image inside. https://wetransfer.com/downloads/50130c59cfad3e34cffdf7dee11d538d20220407094001/3db462

Comment: Thanks, cat looks exactly like my neighbours two cats :) I think what is going on is that one ispe is the real size, one is thumbnail size and a third that i don't think what it used for (the 512x512). Sadly the ISO/IEC 23008-12 specification is not available for free :( https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2017/513fzgbviu23l/513/513_high_efficiency_image_file_format.pdf was quite good at describing some of the box relations

Comment: @MattiasWadman haha cats are everywhere! took me long but I finally found a way to find the right ispe box for my image. There are several ones and you only need to identify which correspond to your "primary" image (this is done through a relation association box). The thing I am stuck at the moment is getting the exif part. Do you have any clue by any chance?

Comment: Nice, so primary image is determined via the "pitm" box item id? had a quick look at the cat image again and i can't see any obvious references to exif or place where exif data would be, also can't find any exif/tiff header (0x49492a00 or 0x4d4d002a). Maybe it's optional?

Comment: correct! the "pitm" points to the primary item and thanks to that you can see which boxes (and therefore which "ispe") are related to the primary item. There is an "exif" in that image, I am sure about it cause I see the marker header but between the header and the actual payload there is a lot in between and that's why I am struggling identifying it. Thanks in any case!!

Comment: Aha, how does the marker look? some mp4 box? maybe we're looking at different files, i see the file in the screenshot have a different size than cat.heic

Comment: @MattiasWadman No indeed the file in the screenshot was totally a different file, but the cat.heic file contains the exif marked exactly with the "exif" marker. They payload of the exif though depends (according to what I read) on the format how the exif is written, for example it could be an XML and in that case (I think) the payload starts with the "cdsc" marker. For now I kinda gave up hahah.. thanks a lot once again for all the help cause you have been super helpful!:)

Comment: Aha no problem, fun to help! btw if the exif in the mp4 is binary (tiff-based) you can use fq to decode it if you want to have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you'r seeing is a "mime" and "ispe" mp4 box as HEIF is ISOBMFF based. I would recommend looking at the file using a mp4 capable tool like mp4dump, HexFiend or [fq](https://github.com/wader/fq) (note: my tool). The "ispe" (Image Spatial Extents) box i probably what you want to read.

fq does no support ispe box yet but you could read it like this:

```
$ fq 'grep_by(.type=="ispe").data | tobytes | [.[-8:-4], .[-4:] | tonumber]' file.heif
[
  8736,
  5856
]
```

So what you need is probably a basic ISOBMFF reader and then look for the "ispe" box and decode it. If you'r only looking for the first of a specific box you can probably ignore that ISOBMFF is a tree structure.

Comment: You can see `ispe` in the hex dump. However the box content are the size before any transformational properties, so that might not be the size of the final image. In particular, it might be rotated (`irot` property) which might mean you'd need to swap the sizes. Scaling  (`iscl`) is also possible, although is probably less common.